# I don't understand why a class is "public"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm beginning to learn C# and I come from a C++ background. The example page I was supposed to create by [these](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller) instructions looks like

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/ 

        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my <b>default</b> action...";
        }

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "This is the Welcome action method...";
        }
    }
}
```

My main question is why the `HelloWorldController` class is prefixed by `public`. I understand that `HelloWorldController` is derived from `Controller`, but why does a class need to be `public` in the first place? My understanding of the words `public` and `private` is that they only have meaning if they're functions inside a class, and that `public` are the ones that can be used by instances of that class. Also, where is my `main.cs` in this Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC project that I created?

Comment: This answer is arguably best served by a good _Learning c# 101_ book or online tutorial rather than a question for SO?

Comment: C# has exactly the same meaning for `public` as C++ in this context. It is very unclear what "public and private is that they only have meaning if they're functions inside a class" mean in C++ or C#

Comment: msdn is great: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

Comment: I Agree with @MickyDuncan. But to help you out: ASP.NET MVC apps don't have (or need) an main.cs. The framework takes care of when things are called and thus isn't like a normal application.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: `public` qualifier on a class has no meaning in C++, so I don't understand what you mean by `same meaning`. I believe the difference is the compilation method. C++ has header files of course.

Comment: @JesseGood Looks like Alexei didn't fully understand the question. His answer is correct if asking about public/private on a method.

Comment: @JesseGood fair point... should be something like "when `public` applies to a C++ class (nested class in public section of parent class) than meaning is *close* to meaning in C#, also unlike C++ in C# access modifiers applied to individual classes/methods/fields". Clearly my comment was not exactly the best example of comments...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of public and private on a class differs from that on methods.

[Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)

```
public class Customer
{
    //Fields, properties, methods and events go here...
}
```

> The class keyword is preceded by the access level. Because public is
>   used in this case, anyone can create objects from this class.

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

```
public class Bicycle
{
    public void Pedal() { }
}
```

> The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same
>   assembly or another assembly that references it.

Comment: I believe the namespace has a part to play? i.e. If I were to call the `Customer` class from another namespace, that would require the class to be public.

Comment: @Ben Namespaces have no role in accessibility. They are merely for logical organization. Assemblies, on the other hand, do play a role. Since assemblies will typically encompass a single namespace, they can be easily confused.

Comment: I realize these are quotes from MSDN but the wording in the first one is misleading. You can create instances of `Customer` because it is also given a public constructor by default, not solely because the class itself is declared public. At the language level, access modifiers control one thing: who can reference a give program element by its name.

Answer (score 1):

A `private` class wouldn't be able to be used by anything, unless it were within another class.  C# doesn't allow un-nested classes to be `private`, as nothing could use it.

However, there is another option: you could mark the class as `internal` instead.  `internal` restricts access to within the current assembly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704544/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-private-class-in-c

Answer (score 1):

The keyword indicates who is allowed to create instances (objects) from this class. Private would be used if you have classes nested inside each other, and you don't won't it accessible from outside the class.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)

> The class keyword is preceded by the access level. Because public is used in this case, anyone can create objects from this class. The name of the class follows the class keyword. The remainder of the definition is the class body, where the behaviour and data are defined. Fields, properties, methods, and events on a class are collectively referred to as class members.